# Is there a way to filter messages in the Windows 8 Mail app to only see unread emails?

Tags: windows-8-mail-app

Is there a way to filter messages in the Windows 8 Mail app to only see unread emails?

I found you can filter messages in your inbox by using the search. With the Mail app open, select Search from the Charms Bar and, for example, a search for "subject:Friday" will filter your inbox to show only emails with the word Friday in the subject. Tokens to: and from: work also. I haven't been able to find a list of valid tokens. Is there a token to only show unread emails?

Or any other way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for closure, the issue was resolved with the update Microsoft released March 2013. They added a drop down above the message pane that lets you toggle between seeing all emails or only unread messages.